# ViewModelLocator Convention Unique to a Module

Tags: prism

Is it possible to have a different ViewModelLocator convention for each Module in a prism WPF application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass whatever you like to `ViewModelLocationProvider.SetDefaultViewTypeToViewModelTypeResolver`, defining any convention you like.

If you can identify the module a view comes from (an attribute on the view type perhaps?), you could look up the associated convention (in registry where each module puts its convention) and use it to find the view model. But it may be easier to make each module register each pair of view and view model using `ViewModelLocationProvider.Register`...

Comment: Can you do it outside the Shell module?  Can Module1 change the provider when it initializes for it's use?

Comment: no, of course not, there can only be one default resolver. but you can make that one look up conventions that modules register somewhere